What are these Pit rewards?
When I complete a Pit run I receive masterworking and crafting mats, obols, gold. And then there is some other thing with some rune symbol next to it, looks like I receive them in thousands, but I cannot figure out what these are. That's definitely not Runeshards as I only have 2k of them.
On this screenshot I received 319,000 of this mysterious reward:

What are these rewards and where can I spend them?

I always assumed this was EXP

As I thought this is the experience point reward for completing the dungeon. You get the same in a Nightmare dungeon.

Here you can see my Rogue's experience before killing the boss and after completing the dungeon.

why would they create a custom symbol instead of "XP" and never explain it in game? why would they award XP in the end game activities where your are already at max level? well, they are a small indie company, they will make it right next time /s

Yeah, at lv100 it would be nice to get more gold for tempering
